# What is the expression to inform that I am having few questions?

Tags: expressions

What would be a nicer way to express "I am having few questions about entering records"?

Comment: That sounds great - you have no problems.

Comment: Note that "I have few questions" means that you're pretty confident you know almost everything you need to know, whereas "I have a few questions" means that you still need more information. "I am having few questions" is not a common English formulation; it sounds like a bad translation.

Answer (score 1):

First off, it would be "I have a few questions about entering records."

But what do you mean by "nicer"? What's not "nice" about the above sentence?

You could make it more polite by saying something like "If you have a few minutes, I have a few questions about entering records." But the original doesn't seem rude at all to me.